# Opening child modal using setTimeout inside parent resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-modal

I have run into an issue using $uibModal and opening another modal window from within the resolve of a parent window, specifically when i use setTimeout to delay the opening it appears that the inner window will not open until the outer window has resolved all its promises in its resolve argument.

The only difference between the working and non working example is the use of setTimeout to delay the inner popup from opening.

**Failing Example - using setTimeout**

```
$scope.doesntWork = function(){
    $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl : 'popup.html',
      resolve : {

        test : function(){
          var q = $q.defer();

          //This inner poppup wont show until the outer one is also
          //allowed to show (Resolve is resolved)
          setTimeout(function(){
            $uibModal.open({
              templateUrl : 'popup_inner.html' 
            });
          },1);

          setTimeout(function(){
            q.resolve(5);

          },2000);
          return q.promise;
        }
      }

    });  
  };
```

**Working Example - No setTimeout**

```
  $scope.works = function(){
    $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl : 'popup.html',
      resolve : {

        test : function(){
          var q = $q.defer();
           $uibModal.open({
              templateUrl : 'popup_inner.html' 
            });

          setTimeout(function(){
            q.resolve(5);

          },2000);
          return q.promise;
        }
      }

    });  
  };
```

Im not sure why this is happening as there is no dependency on the outer popup being opened for the inner popup to open.

see plunkr : [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Zp9q8gUrOeJWLDIX6oRG?p=preview)

**Update**

Interestingly even if you set a modal off before then trying to open another with a resolve argument - it wont show until the resolve is finished on the second modal, even though not related to the first - not a real world scenario i know but i'm keen to understand why.

```
$scope.doesntWork = function(){

    $timeout(function(){
        $uibModal.open({
          templateUrl : 'popup_inner.html' 
        });
    },1);

    //unrelated to the above modal yet blocks it from showing until  
    //resolved finished

    $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl : 'popup.html',
      resolve : {

        test : function(){
          var q = $q.defer();
          setTimeout(function(){
            q.resolve(5);

          },2000);
          return q.promise;
        }
      }

    });  
  };
```

Comment: "inner modal"? ...don't. A UI should never display more than one modal at a time.

Comment: In this particular app a modal window is used as a 'loading' overlay, this issue is happening when showing that overlay while waiting for the promise to resolve of the actual popup window.

Comment: How about just adding a spinner or similar animation at some place in the original modal? Certainly less confusing to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution would be to call $scope.$apply within the timeout.

e.g.

```
setTimeout(function(){
        $scope.$apply(function() {
          $uibModal.open({
          templateUrl : 'popup_inner.html' 
        });
     })
 },1);
```

Tested on plunk and works fine.

Comment: It should also work using `$timeout` instead of `setTimeout` but curiously it doesn't when in test in the Plunkr

Comment: Interesting, $timeout would certainly be the way to go.  I updated the plunkr example, with $timeout injected in the controller and seems to work for me when switching setTimout with $timeout

Comment: interesting - im still unable to get this to work, do you have a link to a working plunkr ?